Why data is not in a recognized alluvial form
I have a dataset of students with their grades and I want to evaluate their evolution over the years.
I've already cleaned up the data, and I've associated each student with his or her quintile within the year (from 1 to 5) and the year of study (A1, A2, or A3).

I want to generate a Sankey Diagram to visualize their evolution, like this one below.

I work on R and I tried to use the ggalluvial package, but it didn't work with a reccurent error.
Here's my code for now:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)
library(dplyr)

# Data loading
data <- read.csv("/mydata.csv")

# Converting Year and Quintile as factors
data$Year <- factor(data$Year, levels = c("A1", "A2", "A3"))
data$Quintile <- as.factor(data$Quintile)
data$individual <- as.factor(data$Student_ID)

# Check the structure of the data
str(data)

# Prepare the data for the alluvial plot
data_long <- data %>%
  select(individual, Year, Quintile) %>%
  group_by(individual, Year, Quintile) %>%
  summarise(Freq = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  ungroup()

# Convert data to lodes format
data_lodes <- to_lodes_form(data_long, key = "Year", value = "Quintile", id = "individual")

# Create the alluvial plot
ggplot(data_lodes, aes(x = Year, stratum = Quintile, alluvium = individual, y = Freq, fill = Quintile, label = Quintile)) +
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", aes(fill = Quintile), lode.guidance = "rightleft", color = "darkgray") +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("A1", "A2", "A3")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Evolution of Student Distribution Across Quintiles", x = "Year", y = "Number of Students", fill = "Quintile")

And the error:
Error in `geom_flow()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_data()`:
! Data is not in a recognized alluvial form (see `help('alluvial-data')` for details).
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I've tried reformatting my data (in particular using the to_lodes_form() function), converting it into factors, but I can't solve the problem.
Any ideas?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

I think this could help: Transition (Sankey) plot with time on x axis
With your data, I believe the following code should work:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

data <- data.frame(Student_ID = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 4), 
                   Quintile = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3), 
                   Year = sort( rep(c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'), 3)))

data$Year <- factor(data$Year, levels = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"))
data$Quintile <- as.factor(data$Quintile)
data$individual <- as.factor(data$Student_ID)

ggplot(data,
       aes(x = Year, stratum = Quintile, alluvium = individual, 
           fill = Quintile, label = Quintile)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 3) +
  geom_flow(fill = "darkgrey", color = "black")


Thanks for your reply. I got the same Error while trying the piece of code you gave. I don't understand why ma data is not recognized as an alluvial form. I tried to simplify as much as possible my data and my code and I still get the same Error again.

I finally understood why my data were unappropriate. I had multiple rows for each student and year. Adding this code resolve my issue.
data_long <- data_long %>%
group_by(individual, Year) %>%
summarize(Quintile = first(Quintile)) %>%
ungroup()
Thanks again

Great, I added a reproducible example for clarity :)
